# Date in wordpress excerpt

Tags: wordpress, date, inline, code-snippets

When I use the_excerpt and the_date they appear on different lines

Is there a way to make them appear inline? I tried wrapping them in divs and styling them that way, but it doesn't work. Can I just do it via code somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Show some HTML code that WP produces

Answer (score 1):

I think `<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>` doesn't wrap the text in paragraphs so you could use them inline with the_date.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 <?php $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=3&offset=0');
            foreach($myposts as $post) :
             setup_postdata($post); ?>
             <li><?php the_excerpt(); ?></li>

             <?php endforeach;
             wp_reset_query();
            ?>
```